# involution in finite simple group

Tags: group-theory

I need your help in following question:

What are finite simple groups whose automorphism groups acts transitively on the set of all involutions of it?

What are finite simple groups whose automorphism groups do not act transitively on the set of all involutions of it?

Comment: What is the action, conjugation in Aut?

Comment: @anon The automorphism group of a group $G$ acts on $G$ by definition.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I was thinking of the involutions in Aut(G) instead of G.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I think it is possible anon got confused by the wording: "...of all involutions on **it** ", and the last "it" that is apparently mentioned is the automorphism group, so ...

Comment: It is possible to answer this question by using the classification of finite simple groups and their known properties. The sporadic groups can be considered individually, the alternating groups  $A_n$have a single class of involutions (under their automorphism group) iff $n=5,6,7$ and for groups of Lie type, only those of low rank might have that property. For example it holds for all ${\rm PSL}_2(q)$. But I am not volunteering to do it for you!